# Как отследить все запросы к базе данных MySql за один сеанс?

Tags: php, mysql

Ранее работал с Yii2 и там все запросы к базе данных можно было посмотреть в дебагере, идущем в комплекте с фрэймворком. Сейчас нужно отлаживать крупный сайт, который написан без использования фрэймворка.

Можно ли каким-то образом, средствами самой базы, отследить все запросы, которые пришли за один сеанс? Это нужно для оптимизации запросов. Устранения дублирующихся запросов и т.д. Возможно, это можно сделать средствами php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Последние запросы можно записать в базу mysql.general_log

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Или в файл

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = "FILE";
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = "/path/to/your/logfile.log";
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```